# What sound (Onomatopoeia) does big lights shutting off sound like

Tags: single-word-requests, onomatopoeia

I'm writing a story about a paranormal tornado and the story starts at a basketball game,
but when the lights shut off and the warning sirens start, I don't know what sound effect
(onomatopoeia) to use.
Could you help me find something?

Comment: Do lights make a sound when they turn off?

Comment: The lights of a stadium or of a basketball court do make a sound... But I have never heard it named specifically. You could describe it as a thud noise of lights turning off...

Comment: Same question as [last time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/576723/what-sound-does-a-tornado-siren-make-onomatopoeia): You say "sound effect," but you're looking for actual, valid words, not something like "skchunk"? (Also, can you clarify what the sound in question sounds like: my first thought is the loud, percussive "chonk" sound presumably made by some sort of solenoid.)

Comment: When ever big stadium lights turn off together, like when the power goes out they make a sound.

Comment: Could you guys post it as an answer not a comment so I can accept it

Comment: I was looking for clarification first: You *are* looking for "real words"? and for the short, loud, percussive sound?

Comment: (Requests for inventions are off-topic on ELU.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the question is asking along the parameters that I believe it is, then "thunk," "clunk," and "clank" convey how much treble is in the sound, from least to most. "Thud" has also been suggested, which conveys a less abrupt cessation to the sound.

Comment: Maybe even an “echoing thunk”  https://youtu.be/6KuL3mT2Wqg   Or “reverberating thunk”

Comment: Adding adjectives would be nice, but the question was tagged single-word-requests

Answer (score 2):

When a large bank of lights (or any other large-scale electrical phenomenon) is shut off, normally transformers shut down and that makes a loud "clunking" sound, like a large metallic object has just been dropped into its position in a much larger machine. Which is pretty close to what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like "Whumpf":

Whumpf! Is a low frequency, slow exhalation sound that lasts about ½ a second - Perhaps like "B-hhh!"

From Avalanche-center.org https://www.avalanche-center.org/Education/glossary/whumpf.php

> Whumpf
>
> Also: Whumpfing, Collapsing, Cracking, Settling (misused)
>
> When there is a weakness buried in the snowpack which has a lot of air space between grains and which is weak under compression a "whumpf" sound may be heard when this weak layer fails and air is compressed out of it.
>
> This may or may not be accompanied by the appearance of shooting cracks.

This sound, with or without cracking, usually indicates a highly unstable situation. The types of failures which produce this "whumpf" sound are ones which can propagate great distances, including upslope from a runout zone.

Answer (score 0):

This is what a 1200 amp light switch looks like. The high-voltage contactors open as the ac voltage crosses over at 0 Volts so they don't spark, but that means they have to open really fast with a big thunk.

[image]

Comment: 'Thunk' has already been given.